How does defining template in vector of map works in c++
I dont know if this is actually possible, but im trying to represent a field visualization in the form of vector of map , where each position is assign a different key and for every key position, it will store a class value, in my case, the value might be class Plant or class Animal, but i just want to try implement it in a simple way first, so say integer. Here is my .cpp:
#include "Grid.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

template <class T>
Grid<T>::Grid(int grid_width, int grid_height){
    cout<<"hello";
    this->grid_width = grid_width;
    this->grid_height = grid_height;
    for (int h = 0; h < grid_height; ++h) {
        map<string, T> row; 
        for (int w = 0; w < grid_width; ++w) {
            char row_char = 'A' + h;
            string code;
            if (w>9){
                code ="0";
            }
            else{
                code="";
            }
            string key = row_char + code + to_string(w + 1);
            row[key] = T();
        }
        grid.push_back(row);
    }
}
template <class T>
int Grid<T>::getWidth() const {
    return grid_width;
}
template <class T>
int Grid<T>::getHeight() const {
    return grid_height;
}
template <class T>
T Grid<T>::getElement(const string& landId) const {
    for (const auto& row : grid) {
        auto it = row.find(landId);
        if (it != row.end()) {
            return it->second;
        }
    }
}
template <class T>
void Grid<T>::showGrid() const {
    for (int w = 0; w < grid_width; ++w) {
        cout << "+------";
    }
    cout << "+" << endl;
    for (int h = 0; h < grid_height; ++h) {
        for (int w = 0; w < grid_width; ++w) {
            cout << "| ";
            char row_char = 'A' + h;
            string key = row_char + (w < 9 ? "0" : "") + to_string(w + 1);
            auto it = grid[h].find(key);
            if (it != grid[h].end()) {
                cout << it->first;
            } else {
                cout << "____";
            }
            cout << " ";
        }
        cout << "|" << endl;
        for (int w = 0; w < grid_width; ++w) {
            cout << "+------";
        }
        cout << "+" << endl;
    }
}

with header of:
#ifndef GRID_H
#define GRID_H
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class Grid {
private:
    std::vector<std::map<std::string, T>> grid;
    int grid_width;
    int grid_height;

public:
    Grid(int grid_width, int grid_height);
    int getWidth() const;
    int getHeight() const;
    T getElement(const std::string& LandId) const;
    void showGrid() const;
};


#endif // GRID_H

And im trying to call it in my main this way:
#include <iostream>
#include "Entity/Grid/Grid.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Grid<int> test(5,5);
    test.showGrid();
    return 0;
}

The error im getting is
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccZbVtb7.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `Grid<int>::Grid(int, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `Grid<int>::showGrid() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I dont get it, i thought template was supposed to cover every form of class?

Since you have a template, you should put your implementation with the declaration. Or in a .hpp file and include the .hpp file instead of the .h file. The compiler cannot find the implementation of Grid<T>. Edit, well, it can. It just can't instantiate it when it needs to.

I tried changing to .hpp but still the same error occurs
edit: it does my bad , but can you explain why it cant get pass the .cpp ( why it should be implemented right there and whats the difference with .h and .hpp)

After changing to .hpp how are you compiling? Did you also change the #include in main?

My bad there are some point im missing, you're right and i am very thankful of your help. Can you explain why it should be implemented right there and whats the difference with .h and .hpp)

I see you have some Python experience, so I'll try to frame it that way. Templates are almost like metaclasses; they can create classes whenever you need them to, setting whatever fields, functions, etc. you want. However, unlike metaclasses, C++ templates don't exist at runtime. (Heck, they hardly exist at compile-time except for syntax checking.) What happens is that at compile-time when you instantiate a template (class/method), only then will something start to exist. That something is your template instantiation. The thing that calls the template needs to be able to see its entire def

(ran out of room above). So, in your case, main needs to be able to "see" the entire definition of Grid<T>. Since you only included .h, it can only see the declaration. If you included .cpp then it would technically see the definition, but .cpp files are usually gobbled up automatically by build systems and told to produce intermediate files (like .o etc) to be linked into the final executable, which is not what you want with templates. So, it's more typical to treat .h as "non-template declaration" and ".hpp" as "template definition, which also includes the declaration"

just look at what the compiler generates for a small code block, https://cppinsights.io/s/d8ed966f (hit the run button) , one cpp can't pull code from another cpp file, it can only pull code from header files, because included headers are copy-pasted into cpp files, templates are just a better copy-paste tool than macros, you need macros to be in the header, and you need templates to be in the header.

When you put the declaration for a class template in a header file, and put the member function definitions in a separate .cpp file, then the compiler cannot instantiate the template when it encounters its use in a file where only the header has been included.
When that happens, the compiler can still allocate an object from the template, because it knows the sizes of its various members. It can also compile calls to any of its member functions, because it has their signatures. It cannot, however, provide the address for any of those functions. It assumes, therefore, that a .cpp file somewhere contains defintions for those functions, and when that file is compiled, the linker will be able to plug in the addresses for the various function calls.
This, of course, is what the compiler does for any externally defined function.
By the time the compiler gets around to compiling the .cpp for the class template, there is a problem. Nothing in the file tells it to instantiate the class for any particular type T. So, therefore, it does not instantiate the template. When the linker goes looking for the function definitions, there are none to be found.
One way to fix this is to use an explicit instantiation.
The following example instantiates the class template Grid for type T equal to int. Note the syntax is similar to that used for a template specialization, but there are no empty angle brackets following the keyword template.
template Grid<int>;  // "explicit instantiation"

If you place that line as the last line of the file Grid.cpp, your program will run.
Define functions within the class template
An alternative is to define all member functions within the template definition in the header file. Then you don't need the explicit instantiation.
